# Gitkraken does not show deleted file in commit view

Tags: gitkraken

In commit 88f076 [(github link)](https://github.com/maxsu/balancers2/commit/88f076f28195867b9f4b6fe9f287cff63b7ba51c) of my repo, I deleted the file `lib/utils.cpp`.

This deletion [appears on github](https://github.com/maxsu/balancers2/commit/88f076f28195867b9f4b6fe9f287cff63b7ba51c):

[image]

and in my git CLI:

```
$ git show 88f076
    Author: Max Suica <max.suica@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 27 10:37:40 2022 -0700

    Fix Header Include Order

    * Use C++ convention (x.cpp includes x.h)
    * Rename c headers (.h) to c++ headers (.hpp)
    * Headerize util.cpp - fixes template function issue

 rename lib/{exists_balancer.h => exists_balancer.hpp} (63%)
 rename lib/{network_tools.h => network_tools.hpp} (96%)
 rename lib/{output_ratios.h => output_ratios.hpp} (82%)
 rename lib/{types.h => types.hpp} (100%)
 delete mode 100644 lib/utils.cpp
 delete mode 100644 lib/utils.h
 create mode 100644 lib/utils.hpp
 rename tests/{test_cases.h => test_cases.hpp} (89%)
 rename tests/{test_utils.h => test_utils.hpp} (60%)
```

However, it does not appear in Gitkraken's commit review:

[image: lib/utils.cpp should appear as a deleted file]

I'm running Gitkraken on Ubuntu, and first discovered this issue on a collaborator's OSX machine.

### To replicate

1. Clone the repo: https://github.com/maxsu/balancers2.git
2. Open in Gitkraken
3. Inspect commit 88f076 - "Fix Header Include Order"

### Question

Why causes Gitkraken to hide this deleted file, and can I configure it to show the file?